# How to install another module when a module is being installed

Tags: installation

I have created a module (*travel_list*) that uses the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module. I want the *Field group* module to be automatically downloaded and installed whenever the *travel_list* module is installed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Drupal, a module doesn't download and install the modules from which it depends. Doing that would fail, as the system account used to run PHP should not have write access to the directory containing the modules. Letting PHP write files in the directory containing the modules, especially if those files contain PHP code, is considered a security issue.

Instead, modules declare their dependencies from other modules in their .info.yml file. In your case, the *travel_list.info.yml* file would contain the following lines.

```
dependencies:
  - field_group:field_group
```

It should also declare its dependencies from Drupal core modules. For example, in the case it also depends from the *Search* module, it should contain the following lines.

```
dependencies:
  - drupal:search
  - field_group:field_group
```

Comment: so where do I put the field group module folder?

Comment: As developer of a module, you don't need to put that module in any place. It's who uses your module that needs to download any module from which yours depends.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3):

If a module depends on another module, you have to declare it as a dependency. The way Drupal handles this, is through the *.info.yml files, which define the basic module attributes.

In 'travel_list.info.yml' add this key:

```
dependencies:
  - field_group:field_group
```

Doing that, whenever you install the module 'travel_list' it will enforce you to install 'field_group'; this means that if you try to install 'travel_list' module and 'field_group' is not installed, the installation will abort reporting that 'field_group' module is needed.

Developing an script that downloads and triggers the module installation is far away from good practices and can lead to a number of unpredicted situations, starting by the fact that the required modules of your Drupal are defined in the composer.json.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the detailed explanation